# Refactoring many identical DllImport declarations

Tags: f#, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a module which contains an interface to a native DLL; it looks like this:

```
// nvtt.dll binding module
module private NvTextureTools =
    type NvttInputOptions = IntPtr

    [<DllImport("nvtt", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
    extern NvttInputOptions nvttCreateInputOptions()

    [<DllImport("nvtt", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
    extern void nvttDestroyInputOptions(NvttInputOptions)

    [<DllImport("nvtt", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
    extern void nvttSetInputOptionsAlphaMode(NvttInputOptions, AlphaMode alphaMode)

    [<DllImport("nvtt", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
    extern void nvttSetInputOptionsGamma(NvttInputOptions, float inputGamma, float outputGamma)

    [<DllImport("nvtt", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
    extern void nvttSetInputOptionsWrapMode(NvttInputOptions, WrapMode mode)
```

(there are 5x more functions, but this should give the general idea).

Is there any way to specify the DllImport parameters just once? As far as I understand, I can't inherit from DllImport (it's sealed, and anyway I don't think it would work if it was not), and I can't use reflection to add the necessary attributes because I need them at compilation time.

I could make a brand new class with P/Invoke methods using reflection, but this will make calling them cumbersome.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about F#, but in C# you can do something like:

```
static const string DllName = "nvtt";

[DllImport(DllName, other params...)]
some function signature

[DllImport(DllName, other params...)=
some function signature
```

So that way the actual string is only declared once - the DllImport attributes themselves all still look a lot alike, but it makes changing things easier.  I think you could do the same with CallingConvention, but I've never tried it with an enum.

Comment: FWIW, the equivalent F# would be: `[<Literal>] let DllName = "nvtt"`

Comment: This with the [<Literal>] comment does not solve my problem fully :) but it taught me about Literal syntax, so I'm accepting this comment - there's no other way that does not use external tools anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are using Visual Studio - it is possible to create a T4 template and generate all those nasty attributes. This is not an F# or VS specific solution however, any code generating tool would work.